# Objective c UIImageView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I am trying to take a `UIImageView` and hide it gradually from bottom to top.

What is the best and most efficient way to do it in Objective-C?
I am looking into `CABasicAnimation` Class and Animation Class.

[image]

Comment: IDK what's the "best efficient" way, but I know a simple way: the `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want know CoreAnimation deeply, I think you can use this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animationA=[CABasicAnimation animation];
animationA.keyPath=@"position.y";
animationA.fromValue=@0;
animationA.toValue=@250;
animationA.duration=3;
animationA.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[yourTestView.layer addAnimation:animationA forKey:@"basic"];
yourTestView.layer.position=CGPointMake(250, 50);
```

or if you want to only support IOS7, you can try learn UIAttachmentBehavior and UIDynamicItemBehavior to achieve more interactive animation.

Comment: thanks ShineWang for your question, but it is not my need.
I want that the image will disappear gradually from the screen.
in the first time I see 100% of the imgae and then 90% 80%....0%
and the image Completely disappear from the view.
Do I need to use with Clip image?

Answer (score 0):

All animations like this use Core Animation and can be done really simply using the block based animations.

For this you would do something like...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.frame = CGRectMake(//the end frame of the image view
                 }];
```

This will then animate the change over the duration given. (3 seconds in this case).

There are other versions that you can find in the docs of `UIView` that give you more options like changing the animation curve or running some code on completion etc...

**NOTE**

This assumes you are not using Auto Layout. If you are using auto layout then the method is exactly the same but you need to change the constraints and then run `[view layoutIfNeeded];` in the `animations` block.